# What is the equivalent to 'play stop' for Play Framework 2.1?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1

What is the equivalent of `play stop` for Play 2.1?

If I did `play start`, how do I cleanly terminate the process?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As stated [in the doc](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/Production):

> When you run the start command, Play forks a new JVM and runs the default Netty HTTP server. The standard output stream is redirected to the Play console, so you can monitor its status.
>
> The server’s process id is displayed at bootstrap and written to the RUNNING_PID file. To kill a running Play server, it is enough to send a SIGTERM to the process to properly shutdown the application.
>
> If you type Ctrl+D, the Play console will quit, but the created server process will continue running in background. The forked JVM’s standard output stream is then closed, and logging can be read from the logs/application.log file.

So I think that you have to use `play run` instead of `play start`. Then you'll be able to use <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> to stop play.

Comment: It's annoying how they changed so much of these simple semantics from Play 1. `play start` used to mean something completely different, and production was achieved using completely different means.

Comment: Yeah, it is completely different; you'll have to re-learn (almost) everything :-(

Comment: `play run` runs in development mode and it is intended for development, not production.

Answer (score 18):

On `Windows` I'm using the following script to kill the currently running play server

```
@echo off
if exist RUNNING_PID (
  setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  set /p PLAY_PID=<RUNNING_PID
  echo killing pid !PLAY_PID!
  taskkill /F /PID !PLAY_PID!
  del RUNNING_PID
  endlocal
)
```

Comment: Works great. Do you have any tips on starting Play applications on Windows? At the moment I'm using "play start" which is fine but I'm thinking about writing a script which will automatically start the app after the server is restarted. The ideal scenario is to wrap the application up in a Windows Service but, from what I've seen, this doesn't seem straightforward.

Comment: +1 -- This works for us.  I'm using it in each of the subfolders for our both our dev and test environments.

Comment: @Ian Some years later, but for community : see the difference between `play run` and `play start` -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/16291499/1579667

Comment: @Benj thanks for the input, but I don't think there was any confusion over whether play run/start should be used. It was more about how to wrap 'play start' into a Windows service which will automatically restart when the system is restated.

Comment: +1 -- This worked great as a "Stop" command for my Windows dev environment. I use this with "Batch Support" commands in Intellij along with a Stage + generated start script to start/stop my play app in Windows IntelliJ.

Answer (score 10):

You can run this script:

```
kill $(cat /your-play-project-path/target/universal/stage/RUNNING_PID)
```

Answer (score 8):

If you ran your app using the `play start` command, issuing the `play stop` command from the app directory does work and will stop the running application server.

I verified this works in Play 2.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

Simply press <kbd>Ctrl + D</kbd> in the console window.

Comment: That exists the console, but the process stays up.

Comment: Yep, you're right.  I always use play run in development and CTRL + D works fine.  In production you'll need to kill the process.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you could modify the build.sbt file [as described here](http://www.technowise.in/2014/12/play-framework-activator-stop-command.html).

```
TaskKey[Unit]("stop") := {
  val pidFile = target.value / "universal" / "stage" / "RUNNING_PID"
  if (!pidFile.exists) throw new Exception("App not started!")
  val pid = IO.read(pidFile)
  s"kill $pid".!
  println(s"Stopped application with process ID $pid")
}
```

However, this only applies to *nix systems.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `<your_server_url>/@kill` , e.g. : `http://localhost:9022/app3/@kill`