# What's the difference between using play start and play run?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I am using play framework 2.0.4,

I noticed that   in the project folder, if I used `play start`, the server responses faster than server started via `play run`. However, user can not access static resources under `public` folder in the server started using  `start` command, so I am wondering what's the `start` default configuration that changing the root directory or do I need to change routes which originally defined as:

```
# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
HEAD    /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `play start` command should be executed when you want to deploy your application on **production mode**. It's response faster, because the *auto-reloading-class* and *other development-supporting-features* are disabled **by default**.

Unlike `play start` command, the `play run` command is best executed on **development mode** because it will enable all *development-supporting-feature* like auto-reloading, eBean DDL generation, and so-on.

Actually, if you have a javascript file on `public/javascripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js`. You still can access to url `http://yourdomain/assets/javascripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js` even if you use `play start` or `play run` because the `public/*` files are mapped to `/assets/*`

And to be noticed that the `play start` command is doing the process in **background**, while `play run` not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think I have figured out the problem why asserts can not be accessed in production mode using `start`: because my program dynamically generate static files, where the start will precompiled *all* files, and it can not access to the dynamically generated static files. But if I want to use the production mode, I don't know how to solve this problem for now.

Comment: Hmm, I just tried to place any text file (say dynamic.file.txt) on `projectname/target/scala-2.10/classes/public/dynamic.file.txt` while the application started (`play start`). And what was happened is, I can access newly added file at URL `http://yourdomain/assets/dynamic.file.txt`.. You may try it, friend! ;)